# Give the duplicate closure more priority than the other close reason

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Let's consider the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60160415/8620333

Two users voted to close the question as "need more focus" then I came to close it as duplicate and the result is a banner with "need more focus" and nothing about my duplicate closure.

I know this is by design and the reason with the most votes will win, but it's not a good thing when it comes to duplicate because we won't show an important information.

In such case, I think we should give the priority to the duplicate closure and adjust the banner accordingly. If I am able to close a question as duplicate then for sure the question is *clear* enough and all the other close reason can be ignored.

I am not implying that the other users didn't understand the question or used a wrong close reason but for sure the question was updated to bring more details (which is the case of the above example)

Comment: But then you're essentially giving all users that can VTC the ability to dupehammer a question under the right circumstances.  Any choice of dup should be reviewed, and already cases of dupehammer closures being reversed because the wrong dupe was selected or the question isn't really a dup.

Comment: I'm pretty sure gold-badgers *do* have this ability already. If two people VTC as whatever, then a gold-badger VTCs as duplicate, the close reason will be displayed as duplicate. But if two people VTC as something (say, "need more focus") and then a *non* gold badger VTCs as duplicate, the close reason is "need more focus". This did not occur here because [you added the CSS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60160415/revisions), so mjolnir powers didn't active and override the other close reasons

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh true, I totally forgot that I have edited the question but my logic still apply. It would be good if the duplicate closure isn't ignored that way

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I am not giving anyone the ability to dupehammer but if a duplicate a closure is one reason among the 3 then it should be shown somewhere. The question will be closed in all the cases but let's at least hightlight the duplicate target because it can be a useful information. Right or wrong is a different story.

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you're the third person closing as dupe you sort of get a link - the auto-generated comment is still posted. But I do agree that it most likely should be more prominent. I had this experience recently where two people voted for other closure reasons and I dupe-voted for the correct (albeit somewhat obscure) dupe target. So, the question was closed as "off-topic" but the "Does this answer your question" comment remained. Not sure how this situation can be amended better but people don't necessarily realise there is a dupe available for a behaviour and vote for other close reasons

Comment: Maybe you were wrong with your close vote as duplicate. Did the comment "does this answer your question" appear at least?

Comment: @Trilarion (1) no I wasn't wrong because if you check the comments you will see that I have closed after the OP confirmed that my fix was indeed correct (2) yes that comment appear but you need to expand all the comment to find it. Also, even if we consider the fact I was wrong closing as duplicate, the information is still useful because it can be true.

Comment: So what you want is basically display all the given close reasons not only the most popular one. I'm not against it, but I think this is likely already discussed before.

Comment: @Trilarion not all of them but in case a duplicate is involved either make it always the winner or display it somewhere. I want the duplicate information to be visible

Comment: While the question is unclear, the duplicate is typically just a guess & even if the asker says that's what their question was the post is unclear so a duplicate heading isn't helping anyone searching later--they too would be guessing.

Comment: I just ran into a problem that this would solve/have prevented: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397961/7509065

Comment: @philipxy no it was not a guess and will never be a guess. If I vote to close as duplicate then I am sure it's a duplicate and the question is clear enough to me to identify the duplicate. By the way, there is many other reason to close question among *unclear* and even if we consider the fact that the duplicate is a guess, it remains an important information that should be shown somewhere. I have seen a lot of people closing question as unclear simply because they don't understand the topic while I have clearly understood the question in order to either answer it or close it as duplicate.

Comment: Just ran into this exact occurrence today: user asked a question, two users VTC'd as lacks focus, a different user suggested a question as a dupe in a comment, to which the asker replied and confirmed that was what they were asking - I thus VTC'd as dupe pointing to the dupe - boom, question is closed as lacks focus with no indication that it's actually a dupe.