# What should I do if I find a duplicate of a question that already has 2 non-duplicate close votes?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Today, I came across the question [What are the differences between malloc(3posix) and malloc(3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62174173/7509065). I knew this was a duplicate of [Linux newbie: Linux vs POSIX manual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/479173/7509065), but the question already had two close votes as "unclear what you're asking". As a result, when I cast my close vote, the question was immediately closed, but not as a duplicate. As a result, the link to where to find the answer is now buried under a "show **6** more comments" link instead of being immediately visible at the top of the page. While this isn't that bad for the asker since they'll have gotten a notification of my comment, it is bad for anyone else who may come across this question later.

Three questions:

- Should I have originally done something other than casting the close vote?
- Now that the question is closed, what should be done about it?
- Is there a way we can improve this in the general case (as it isn't the first time this has happened to me, and I assume it's happened to others too)?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393920/8620333

Comment: I think gold-badge duplicate always wins... So if someone confirms that it is indeed how such votes are treated it may  be the answer - get gold-badge.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov not with the low upvoting quota that plagues us newish users

Comment: To answer your specific question, there's nothing really you can do as it stands now, other than leaving a link. Perhaps you could find a gold badge holder or a moderator in a chat room (e.g., SOCVR or a language-specific chat room), but that won't always be an option. I've handled this case, as someone who knows the topic domain. In the long run, I think what is suggested in the feature request that I've closed this as a duplicate of is the best idea.